# Where can I find tutorials for LWJGL?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I don't know if this is against the FAQ so if you close this, it'll be no surprise.
I have done research but all the tutorials I have seen have been to hard to follow; I reckon there are better ones out there.
If you could tell me, that would be great but if you close it, I understand.
Thank you

Comment: What about the tutorials is hard to follow? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make a game with LWJGL but I can't really understand the code like this:- `GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS)` e.tc. I mean with the lighting and all the high-end code, I really need to know it but can't find a good tutorial.

Comment: Not really an answer to your original question, but a remark to the answer above. OpenGl should would the same generally in both C++ and Java. (Sure there will be small differences, but *glLoadIdentity* for example will work the same in Java as C++. So any general tutorial on OpenGl will help you. Even if it is written for OpenGl in an obscure language.

Comment: Check the answers of this SO question : [Latest LWJGL tutorial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416287/latest-lwjgl-tutorial/29468510#29468510)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to read *[Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html)* and check out my [LWJGL port](https://github.com/integeruser/jgltut), but if you don't understand glBegin and GL_QUADS maybe you'll find it a bit too difficult for now. Give it a look.

Also, in the official [LWJGL wiki](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Learning_LWJGL) are listed some resources that can help you to start.

Comment: Thank you so much, your tutorials are awesome and I can actually understand them!!! Thank you, I would rep you but I can't :P

Comment: One thing I just noticed, I think you are doing it in C++, not Java. Are you? :'(

Comment: The original book (which is not mine) is written in C++, but if you check the second link (*LWJGL port*) you'll find the same code rewritten using LWJGL. :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at ["Java Game Development" LWJGL tutorials from The Coding Universe](http://goo.gl/R09CC). They are really good and can help you to understand LWJGL better.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Coding Universe tutorials that Denys P. mentioned I would recommend taking a look at [thenewboston's YouTube videos](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL210C2267A8922854) parts 1-12

He hasn't added the additional videos to a playlist, so I created one [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9BA7E13950409F54&feature=plcp) parts 13-21

They are strictly 2D and focused and using [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) library but can help you get started.

Good luck!
-Mitchell

Comment: Does he do LWJGL tutorials because I watched his tutorials before on basic Java?

Comment: Slick2D is written with LWJGL. LWJGL, as I understand it, doesn't do a whole lot on it's own. It gives you cross platform access to input, display, etc. The real work comes with OpenGL or another library. I think you should think of LWJGL as the foundation and then pick another tool to build with from there. If you want to build 3D games OpenGL is the way to go. For that I would say integeruser's post or Denys P. are for you. If you are looking to build 2D games then I think thenewboston is a great place to start. I'm very new to this, so my advice may be a bit flawed, proceed with caution.